# Issue with presenting UIDocumentInteractionController in a custom class

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I created a custom class named `PreviewFile`:

```
class PreviewFile: UIViewController , UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {

     var documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController()


    func previewFile(name:String)  {

        let documentsURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!,isDirectory: true )
        let urlToMyPath = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(name)!

        documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: urlToMyPath)
        documentInteractionController.delegate = self
        documentInteractionController.presentPreview(animated: true)

    }



    public  func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {

        return self

    }

}
```

Then I call the `previewFile` method on a ViewController :

```
var preview = PreviewFile()
preview.previewFile(name:"guide.pdf")
```

But compiler gives me this error :

> Warning: Attempt to present  on
>    whose view is not in the window
>   hierarchy!

Comment: What you are doing here from this line var preview = PreviewFile()
this line only take copy of the class but not the View attached to that class.
try 
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "someViewController") as! yourViewControllerClass
and call like this
controller.previewFile(name:"guide.pdf")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class PreviewFile: UIViewController , UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {

    private var controller: UIViewController!

    func previewFile(name:String, in controller: UIViewController)  {
        self.controller = controller
        let documentsURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!,isDirectory: true )
        let urlToMyPath = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(name)!

        let documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: urlToMyPath)
        documentInteractionController.delegate = self
        documentInteractionController.presentPreview(animated: true)

    }



    public func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {

        return self.controller

    }

}
```

then you will be able to call it from UIViewController like that:

```
var preview = PreviewFile()
preview.previewFile(name:"guide.pdf", in self)
```

You have this issue because you are trying to show documentDirectory from PreviewFile controller, what is not presented on screen

UPDATE #1
Better solution

```
class PreviewFile: NSObject, UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {
private var controller: UIViewController!

init(controller: UIViewController) {
    super.init()
    self.controller = controller
}

func previewFile(name:String)  {
    let documentsURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!,isDirectory: true )
    let urlToMyPath = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(name)!

    let documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: urlToMyPath)
    documentInteractionController.delegate = self
    documentInteractionController.presentPreview(animated: true)
}


public func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {

    return self.controller

}
}
```

call it like that:

```
var preview = PreviewFile(controller: self)
preview.previewFile(name:"guide.pdf")
```

Comment: Thanks ! I did not noticed that